# How to check which points are inside a circle?

Tags: python, geometry, patch, point

I have a dataframe `df` that contains the distances between all the points (`IDs`) in my system. So the `df` looks like the following:

```
df
    radius      ID1     ID2     x1          y1          x2          y2
0   0.454244    100     103     103.668919  1.335309    103.671812  1.332424
1   1.016734    100     123     103.668919  1.335309    103.677598  1.332424
2   0.643200    103     123     103.671812  1.332424    103.677598  1.332424
3   1.605608    100     124     103.668919  1.335309    103.677598  1.346851
4   1.728349    103     124     103.671812  1.332424    103.677598  1.346851
```

I want to compute the circle between all the points and then check witch points are inside that circle. For each points I have the coordinates in a separated dataframe `coordinates`.

```
coordinates
    ID      x           y
0   100     103.668919  1.335309
1   103     103.671812  1.332424
2   124     103.677598  1.346851
3   125     103.677598  1.349737
4   134     103.680491  1.341080
5   135     103.680491  1.343966
6   136     103.680491  1.346851
7   137     103.680491  1.349737
8   138     103.680491  1.352622
9   146     103.683384  1.341080
```

Here the code

```
from matplotlib.patches import Circle 

for i in df.index:
    x = df.x1[i]
    y = df.y1[i]
    circ = Circle((x, y), radius = df.radius)
    ## it works until here: from now I need to understand what to do 
    ## and in particular I need to find which points are inside the circle

    points = circ.contains_point([coordinates.x, coordinates.y])
```

which returns the error

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: What do you mean with *the circle between all the points*. If it is a cricle between all these points, then aren't all the points by definition in the circle?

Comment: what is your question? Isn't `circ.contains_point([coordinates.x, coordinates.y])` working?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I need to find all the points inside the circle I created with that radius.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Exaclty: `circ.contains_point([coordinates.x, coordinates.y])` is not working

Comment: do you get an error? what happens when you try your code?

Comment: can you create a [mcve] ? with fixed values?

Comment: @CodeCupboard I modified the code according to my real data and to the error that I get

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I tried to create the example with the data I am working on

Comment: I think part of your issue might be that `coordinates.x` and `coordinates.y` are collections of values rather than a single point. I think you just need to index those with the same index used on the dataframe.

Comment: I'm _sure_ that `coordinates.x` is a collection. You have to use a loop on zipped x,y values instead.

Answer (score 6):

When I have issues like this, I always do a small sanity test:

```
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
circ = Circle((0, 0), radius = 1)

print(circ.contains_point([0.5,0.5]))
print(circ.contains_point([2,2]))
```

I get (as expected)

```
True
False
```

So `coordinates.x` and `coordinates.y` are probably arrays, which explains the message.

`contains_points` works on a `tuple` or `list` of 2 scalars.

To generate your list, you could do a loop within a list comprehension:

```
points = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(coordinates.x, coordinates.y) if circ.contains_point(x,y)]
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Even if I do `circ.contains_point([0,1])` it returns `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: I have tested this `circ.contains_point([0,1])` and it works. have you checked the traceback python gives you?